# Failed getting available Android API levels. Unity 2018.4

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk

Hello I am using unity 2018.4 and also I have lasted sdk tool but I am getting following warning

```
Failed getting available Android API levels. Make sure your android sdk tools version is 25 or higher and you have internet connection.
System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart()
```

I don't why I am getting this warning plz help

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in the message you get? Have you checked your SDK Version?

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/failed-getting-available-android-api-levels-make-sure-your-android-sdk-tools-version-is-25-or-highe.619780/

Comment: Yes I have latest sdk but i am getting this warning yesterday i dwonload the sdk tools from the android site.